# Ensuring I don't push passwords to GitHub for my Flutter development

Tags: android-studio, flutter, github

I have an API key that my Flutter app uses but I don't want it pushed to GitHub.

I have thought about putting it as a const in a specific .dart file and then ensuring that the file is included within my .gitignore.

Is there a better practice for this? By the way, if it's helpful, I'm using Android Studio.

Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your project, the best practice is to put your API key as an environnement variable.

You could do as such:

```dart
String? get token => Platform.environment['MY_API_TOKEN'];
```

Also a good practice is to add [Git Guardian](https://www.gitguardian.com/) to manage your repository.
If the robot detect any token/api key, he'll send you an email ASAP.
It can be useful if you're dealing with a lot of rules in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thank you, storing in an envronment variable makes good sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a `.env` config file as [described here](https://artem-diashkin.medium.com/flutter-using-environment-variables-24a976ae1335). This will make it easy to swap out the API key for different environments if necessary.

You must then include the `.env` file in your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thank you Will Taylor. I used the flutter_dotenv, which was very simple to implement.